# A nice way to pass complex result types in JOOQ

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I have been playing with some of the new features of JOOQ 3.17 such as type safe nested table records mixed with implicit joins as is described here:

https://blog.jooq.org/projecting-type-safe-nested-tablerecords-with-jooq-3-17/

We have a complex view where you can modify many properties of a "company" object.  Our old code had a zillion hibernate methods to CRUD related records for the company object on one rather large UI.  Now I want to rewrite this in JOOQ.  I came up with a single query that pulls a CompanyRecord and related records like this:

```
Record4<CompanyRecord, Result<ServiceCompanyPreferenceRecord>, Result<SubsidiaryRecord>, Result<CompanyCo2ParameterRecord>> fancyTypeResult =
        dslContext.get().select(
                        Tables.COMPANY,
                        multiset(
                                selectFrom(Tables.SERVICE_COMPANY_PREFERENCE)
                                        .where(Tables.SERVICE_COMPANY_PREFERENCE.COMPANY_ID.eq(Tables.COMPANY.ID))
                        ),
                        multiset(
                                selectFrom(Tables.SUBSIDIARY)
                                        .where(Tables.SUBSIDIARY.COMPANY_ID.eq(Tables.COMPANY.ID))
                        ),
                        multiset(
                                selectFrom(Tables.COMPANY_CO2_PARAMETER)
                                        .where(Tables.COMPANY_CO2_PARAMETER.COMPANY_ID.eq(Tables.COMPANY.ID))
                        )
                )
                .from(Tables.COMPANY)
                .where(Tables.COMPANY.ID.eq(companyId))
                .fetchOne();
```

This is fantastic because I can modify and save the CompanyRecord or and related ServiceCompanyPreferenceRecord, SubsidiaryRecord,or CompanyCo2ParameterRecord and those rows in the db are updated.

One problem I am having is passing type `"Record4<CompanyRecord, Result<ServiceCompanyPreferenceRecord>, Result<SubsidiaryRecord>, Result<CompanyCo2ParameterRecord>>"` is rather verbose.  So having a function that finds a company all all records like this

```
public Record4<CompanyRecord, Result<ServiceCompanyPreferenceRecord>, Result<SubsidiaryRecord>, Result<CompanyCo2ParameterRecord>> loadCompanyAndRelatedPreferences(Long companyId){ ....
```

Could be a bit akward.  I am wondering if simply making a POJO that holds a field of type `"Record4<CompanyRecord, Result<ServiceCompanyPreferenceRecord>, Result<SubsidiaryRecord>, Result<CompanyCo2ParameterRecord>>"` would make it easier as I can use that POJO without re-writing that type over and over.  Another thought would be is this a good use case for Java records?

We have a number of screens that follow this pattern.  Pull a record and related records, CRUD them.  Any ideas on a nice way to handle this?

Comment: It looks like I can call fetchInto(SomeRecordClass.class) but this has no compile time checking that the result from JOOQ matches with the constructor of the Record Class.  By record I mean JDK16 records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `convertFrom` and `mapping`. Here's an example from https://github.com/72services/jtaf4

```
return dsl
        .select(
            COMPETITION.NAME,
            COMPETITION.COMPETITION_DATE,
            COMPETITION.ALWAYS_FIRST_THREE_MEDALS,
            COMPETITION.MEDAL_PERCENTAGE,
            multiset(
                select(
                    CATEGORY.ABBREVIATION,
                    CATEGORY.NAME,
                    CATEGORY.YEAR_FROM,
                    CATEGORY.YEAR_TO,
                    multiset(
                        select(
                            CATEGORY_ATHLETE.athlete().FIRST_NAME,
                            CATEGORY_ATHLETE.athlete().LAST_NAME,
                            CATEGORY_ATHLETE.athlete().YEAR_OF_BIRTH,
                            CATEGORY_ATHLETE.athlete().club().NAME,
                            multiset(
                                select(
                                    RESULT.event().ABBREVIATION,
                                    RESULT.RESULT_,
                                    RESULT.POINTS
                                )
                                    .from(RESULT)
                                    .where(RESULT.ATHLETE_ID.eq(CATEGORY_ATHLETE.athlete().ID))
                                    .and(RESULT.COMPETITION_ID.eq(COMPETITION.ID))
                                    .and(RESULT.CATEGORY_ID.eq(CATEGORY.ID))
                                    .orderBy(RESULT.POSITION)
                            ).convertFrom(r -> r.map(mapping(CompetitionRankingData.Category.Athlete.Result::new)))
                        )
                            .from(CATEGORY_ATHLETE)
                            .where(CATEGORY_ATHLETE.CATEGORY_ID.eq(CATEGORY.ID))
                    ).convertFrom(r -> r.map(mapping(CompetitionRankingData.Category.Athlete::new)))
                )
                    .from(CATEGORY)
                    .where(CATEGORY.SERIES_ID.eq(COMPETITION.SERIES_ID))
                    .orderBy(CATEGORY.ABBREVIATION)
            ).convertFrom(r -> r.map(mapping(CompetitionRankingData.Category::new)))
        )
        .from(COMPETITION)
        .where(COMPETITION.ID.eq(competitionId))
        .fetchOne(mapping(CompetitionRankingData::new));
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like I can call fetchOneInto(SomeRecordClass.class) but this has no compile time checking that the result from JOOQ matches with the constructor of the Record Class. By record I mean JDK16 records.

```
public record CompanyAndPreferencesNice(CompanyRecord company,
                                        CompanyCo2ParameterRecord companyCo2Parameter,
                                        CompanyAccessCodeRecord companyAccessCode,
                                        Result<SubsidiaryRecord> subsidiaries,
                                        Result<CompanyAreaPreferenceRecord> companyAreaPreferences,
                                        Result<CompanySubareaPreferenceRecord> companySubareaPreferences,
                                        Result<ManifestDocumentPreferenceRecord> documentPreferences,
                                        Result<ServiceCompanyPreferenceRecord> serviceCompanyPreferences) {}


    return dslContext.get()
            .select(
                    COMPANY_CO2_PARAMETER.company(),
                    COMPANY_CO2_PARAMETER,
                    COMPANY_ACCESS_CODE,
                    multiset(
                            selectFrom(SUBSIDIARY)
                                    .where(SUBSIDIARY.COMPANY_ID.eq(companyId).and(SUBSIDIARY.ACTIVE.isTrue()))),
                    multiset(
                            selectFrom(COMPANY_AREA_PREFERENCE)
                                    .where(COMPANY_AREA_PREFERENCE.COMPANY_ID.eq(companyId).and(COMPANY_AREA_PREFERENCE.DELETED.isFalse()))),
                    multiset(
                            selectFrom(COMPANY_SUBAREA_PREFERENCE)
                                    .where(COMPANY_SUBAREA_PREFERENCE.COMPANY_ID.eq(companyId).and(COMPANY_SUBAREA_PREFERENCE.DELETED.isFalse()))),
                    multiset(
                            selectFrom(MANIFEST_DOCUMENT_PREFERENCE)
                                    .where(MANIFEST_DOCUMENT_PREFERENCE.COMPANY_ID.eq(companyId).and(MANIFEST_DOCUMENT_PREFERENCE.DELETED.isFalse()))),
                    multiset(
                            selectFrom(SERVICE_COMPANY_PREFERENCE)
                                    .where(SERVICE_COMPANY_PREFERENCE.COMPANY_ID.eq(companyId).and(SERVICE_COMPANY_PREFERENCE.DELETED.isFalse()))
                    ))
            .from(COMPANY_CO2_PARAMETER, COMPANY)
            .leftJoin(COMPANY_ACCESS_CODE).on(COMPANY_ACCESS_CODE.COMPANY_ID.eq(companyId))
            .where(COMPANY.ID.eq(companyId))
            .and(COMPANY_CO2_PARAMETER.COMPANY_ID.eq(companyId))
            .fetchOneInto(CompanyAndPreferencesNice.class);
```

I could also call fetchOne to return a typesafe Tuple then pass that as the sole value into a JDK 16 record like this...

```
public record CompanyAndPreferences(
        org.jooq.Record8<CompanyRecord, CompanyCo2ParameterRecord, CompanyAccessCodeRecord, Result<SubsidiaryRecord>, Result<CompanyAreaPreferenceRecord>, Result<CompanySubareaPreferenceRecord>, Result<ManifestDocumentPreferenceRecord>, Result<ServiceCompanyPreferenceRecord>> jooqRecord) {
}
    final var record = dslContext.get()
            .select(
                    COMPANY_CO2_PARAMETER.company(),
                    COMPANY_CO2_PARAMETER,
                    COMPANY_ACCESS_CODE,
                    multiset(
                            selectFrom(SUBSIDIARY)
                                    .where(SUBSIDIARY.COMPANY_ID.eq(companyId).and(SUBSIDIARY.ACTIVE.isTrue()))),
                    multiset(
                            selectFrom(COMPANY_AREA_PREFERENCE)
                                    .where(COMPANY_AREA_PREFERENCE.COMPANY_ID.eq(companyId).and(COMPANY_AREA_PREFERENCE.DELETED.isFalse()))),
                    multiset(
                            selectFrom(COMPANY_SUBAREA_PREFERENCE)
                                    .where(COMPANY_SUBAREA_PREFERENCE.COMPANY_ID.eq(companyId).and(COMPANY_SUBAREA_PREFERENCE.DELETED.isFalse()))),
                    multiset(
                            selectFrom(MANIFEST_DOCUMENT_PREFERENCE)
                                    .where(MANIFEST_DOCUMENT_PREFERENCE.COMPANY_ID.eq(companyId).and(MANIFEST_DOCUMENT_PREFERENCE.DELETED.isFalse()))),
                    multiset(
                            selectFrom(SERVICE_COMPANY_PREFERENCE)
                                    .where(SERVICE_COMPANY_PREFERENCE.COMPANY_ID.eq(companyId).and(SERVICE_COMPANY_PREFERENCE.DELETED.isFalse()))
                    ))
            .from(COMPANY_CO2_PARAMETER, COMPANY)
            .leftJoin(COMPANY_ACCESS_CODE).on(COMPANY_ACCESS_CODE.COMPANY_ID.eq(companyId))
            .where(COMPANY.ID.eq(companyId))
            .and(COMPANY_CO2_PARAMETER.COMPANY_ID.eq(companyId))
            .fetchOne();
    var companyAndPreferences = new CompanyAndPreferences(record);
```

This is more verbose but gives compile time checking.  If I ever change the query result type it will give a compile error.

Comment: Just to give some context, there had always been `into(Class<E>):E` and `into(RecordMapper<R, E>):E` style methods in jOOQ - the former is mapping things via the `RecordMapperProvider` SPI (defaulting to `DefaultRecordMapper`, which uses reflection), the latter is a type safe, functional API. The choice is always entirely up to you, but the best practice with nesting collections and records is to stick with the latter API, leveraging type safety